# PHP not parsing XML in expected format?

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to pull [this data](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2015) into PHP, ultimately get it into Javascript so I can make some graphs.

When I download the data using cURL from my mac terminal, I open it in xCode and it looks exactly as expected. No issues accessing the website for data:

```
curl "http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/‌​XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2015" > test.xml
open test.xml
```

When I try to pull into PHP, the xml looks very different. For example, the **d:BC_1MONTH** tag just isn't present:

```
$url = "http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/XmlView.aspx?data=yieldyear&year=2015";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

How do i use php to get XML data in the same format as it is on the website and with cURL download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r()` doesn't work as expected with `SimpleXMLElement` objects. You should do this instead: `echo $xml->asXML()`

When I did that with your code above I saw the element you were asking about.